# 3NF normalized database

Tags: mysql, database, 3nf

I am having trouble creating a 3NF normalized database.  Can anyone help please?  I can't see any dependencies.  This is for a real estate site.  The table fields are as follows:

ID -  Type  -  Loc  -  Village  -  Purpose  -  Price Range  -  Picture 1  -  Picture 2  -  Picture 3  -  Status  -  Properties  -  Description

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can specify what each attribute represents?

Comment: _"Picture 1 - Picture 2 - Picture 3"_ You are not in the 1NF, yet. You might want to add an explanation for each column, as to what type of data it will hold, so we will see what goes where.

Comment: Normalization to BCNF depends on knowing the functional dependencies. FDs aren't determined by column names, even if they're descriptive enough to tell us what they mean. FDs are determined by values and their meaning. You (the OP) are the only one that knows the FDs. You'll find no end of people who are happy to guess, but I think you'll find that guessing doesn't scale well.

Answer (score 0):

If type is a reference to another table, it's ok, else you must put the types in another table. Also you can create a table for the pictures. Village can go in another table if you want more info about the villages after.

Comment: Type represents either an apartment,land, building etc.. The village is used to specify the village so the query can be narrowed down.  For now they are all inside one table.  How should i go about changing it?  thanks for your response

Comment: Not true. As long as type is uniquely determined by ID, and it in turn doesn't uniquely identify anything else, your suggestion has nothing to do with 3NF.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, you are right, in this context, it can remains in the table, but this is for a real work, not homework, so in my opinion, is better having type and village in another table for future system expansion.

Comment: @Renato: Fair enough, but it might be confusing to readers to answer a question about normal forms with a discussion of unrelated design principles.

Comment: @Thomas You are correct, I did my answer based on what I think is better for the system and is not related to the 3NF.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'd have tables like this:

```
            PropertyType
            Village
            Purpose
            Status
            Property
```

and there could be many properties in a particular village.   Purpose and PropertyType might be dependent -- you could not use a Cottage as a gathering place for a large audience, for example, though you could use a Cottage as a "Single Family Dwelling" or as "Bed and Breakfast". To represent this dependency you would need this intermediary table:

```
           PropertyTypePurposes
           propertytypeid
           purposeid
```

where for each property type you would have one or more potential purposes.   Then, in your Properties table, you would not reference Purposes directly but would reference PropertyTypePurposes:

```
           alter table properties
           add constraint FK_PROPERTIES_PROPERTYTYPEPURPOSES
           foreign key (propertytypeid, purposeid) references PropertyTypePurposes(propertypeid, purposeid)
```

Comment: Those still might not be functional dependencies, if you can use a cottage for more than one thing, and several buildings may be used to satisfy a purpose. Your multiplicity suggestions, by the way, are completely beside the point.

Answer (score 0):

To be in 3NF, all you need to ensure is that you don't have any transitive functional depencencies (and that you don't have any non-full dependencies). If ID determines a tuple, and none of the other attributes can be used to say for certain what the value of some other attribute must be, you're not only in 3NF, but also in BCNF.

Comment: Transitive dependencies aren't the *only* criterion for determining whether a relation is in 3NF. It also has to be in 2NF. The OP's relation isn't likely to be in 2NF.

Comment: Good point. That being said, assuming that ID is the key, there can't be any non-full dependencies.

Comment: "Picture 1 - Picture 2 - Picture 3" suggests a repeating group to me. If it is, then the original isn't even in 1NF.